# How to accurately recreate a circular design for 3D print?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, measurement

I know there is an easy way to build this but I can not figure out how. Can anyone walk me through the steps to build the following figure easily? I need to basically have a 1/8" circle with 1/8" straight pieces extruding out every 45 degrees.

[image]

Comment: I think you should rewite the question trying to focus more on what your difficulties are in the modeling (exact measures? topology? extruding?...) or specific workflow doubts. Try too keep the question "wide", so it can be useful for other simiar issue too. The risk is that the question will not be well received and abandoned.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Blender was never meant for precision work</s>. 
One way to get similar results is to use arrays.

Start with proper sized small segments. Add curve + array modifier arround its circle part,

For circumference extrusions it's similar. Use 'object offset' setting in an array modifier.

[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42180)
[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this. Are there any easier ways to make this item?

Comment: Believe me, I made already several models for print's with this method. It's the best way. Here a more detailed tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVGW3fyOkEc
Trust me, I'm an Engineer ;-)
For 3D Print Models, use as much modifiers as possible!

Answer (score 0):

I always do it this way:

1. create the circle
2. create the rectangle
3. move the origin of the rectangle to the origin of the circle (other wise the rotate will later not rotate around the correct centre)
4. duplicate the rectangle and rotate the desired angle
5. hit shift-r to repeat (this automatically duplicates and rotates the rectangle)

Comment: The problem of your way is, that it cannot be adjustet after it is done. With an Array and an empty with roation, like in the other awnser it is afterwards readustable.